# org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, java-8, classformatexception

I'm porting a webapp from Tomcat 7 to another server with Tomcat 7 but with Java 8.

Tomcat starts successfully but in log `catalina.out` I get:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2049)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1931)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1899)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1885)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1100)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You need aspectJ 1.8 to get Java 8 support. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801950/spring-4-and-java-8-invalid-byte-tag-exception

Comment: @AnantLaxmikantBobde That is unrelated to the cause of this problem, which is a bytecode incompatibility between that specific version of Tomcat and that version of the JDK. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118296/2074605) for the correct fix.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The "offical answer" is that Tomcat 7 runs on Java 8, see
http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html ("Java version 6 and later").

However, if annotation scanning is enabled (metadata-complete="true" in web.xml) there are some issues due to BCEL (not able to process the new Java 8 byte codes). You will get exceptions like (at least with Tomcat 7.0.28):

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [jdk/nashorn/internal/objects/NativeString.class] from Jar [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_5/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:131)
```

If **not** using annotation scanning, everything works fine, starting release 7.0.53 (updated compiler with better Java 8 support).

(UPDATE 2014-10-17)
If your **are** using annotation scanning **and** your own code is not Java 8 based, another solution is to add the following line in `/etc/tomcat7/catalina.properties` (text added after "ant-launcher.jar" so part of property `tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip`):

```
junit.jar,junit-*.jar,ant-launcher.jar,\
jfxrt.jar,nashorn.jar
```

Tested with Tomcat 7.0.28 and Oracle JDK 8_25 on Debian 7.6.

Comment: Tomcat 7.054 still doesnt support the jdk8 -compiler flag, related question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279729/tomcat-7-annotation-scanner-and-jdk-8-with-parameters-compiler-flag-exceptions

Comment: To clarify: If metadata-complete="true" is in web.xml annotation processing should be disabled, right?

Comment: Probably, the comment is outdated, but changing the tomcat from 7.0.23 to 8.0.18 automatically solves the issue for me [Windows 7]

Comment: Modifiying tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip within catalina.properties worked for Tomcat 8 for me. (At least it revealed other issues!)

Comment: @SamuelThompson See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118296/2074605) for the correct fix for Tomcat 8.

Comment: The jarsToSkip method solves the OP's exception but may prevent some JARs from loading, it happened to me with log4j2, which would agree with [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html#:~:text=web%20application%20startup.-,Important%20Note,-!%20For%20performance)

Answer (score 40):

This was a [Tomcat bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60688) that resurfaced again with the Java 9 bytecode. The exact versions which fix this (for both Java 8/9 bytecode) are:

- trunk for 9.0.0.M18 onwards
- 8.5.x for 8.5.12 onwards
- 8.0.x for 8.0.42 onwards
- 7.0.x for 7.0.76 onwards

Comment: This solved the problem for me (JDK 8 with Tomcat 8.0.27 failed)

Comment: I get this problem with tomcat 8.0.36 and log4j-api-2.11.0.jar

Comment: This solved the problem. Update your Tomcat version

Answer (score 9):

Update to Tomcat 7.0.58 (or newer).

See: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57173#c16

> The performance improvement that triggered this regression has been
>   reverted from from trunk, 8.0.x (for 8.0.16 onwards) and 7.0.x (for
>   7.0.58 onwards) and will not be reapplied.

Comment: I did not find any relation to java 8 in this link.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem when running my spring boot application with tomcat7:run

It gives error with the following dependency in maven pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.0/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Jul 09, 2020 1:28:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.0/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
```

But when I correctly specify it in test scope, it does not give error:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is happening because you have installed jre1.8.0_101-1.8.0_101-fcs.i58.rpm as well jdk-1.7.0_80-fcs.x86_64.rpm. so just uninstall your jre rpm & restart your application. It should work out.

Answer (score 2):

To me, upgrading bcel to 6.0 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked, by removing the jars in question from the war.
With Maven, I just had to exclude for example

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
                <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>txw2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.fastinfoset</groupId>
                <artifactId>FastInfoset</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/xxxxxxxx/lombok-1.18.4.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
```

1.update and append below argument in `<root or instance tomcat folder>/conf/catalina.properties`

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=...,lombok-1.18.4.jar
```

2.clean and deploy the to-be-published project.

Comment: I had to revert to **1.14.8** version (AFAIK with the same principal features, so no big deal here)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with tomcat 7 + jdk 1.8

with java 1.7 and lower versions it's working fine.

window -> preferences -> java -> installed jre

in my case I changed 
jre1.8 to JDK 1.7

and accordingly modify project facet , select same java version as it's there in selected Installed JRE.

Comment: @AshishRatan See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118296/2074605) for the correct fix for JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error (org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15) while using aspectj 1.8.13. Solution was to align all compilation into jdk 8 and being careful not to put aspectj library's (1.6.13 for instance) other versions to buildpath/classpath.