# Tomcat 7 Annotation scanner and JDK 8 with -parameters compiler flag exceptions

Tags: java, tomcat, annotations, java-8

I am compiling my classfiles with JDK 8 with the -parameters flag which preserves the parameter names and makes them available via reflection. Tomcat 7 seems to have issues with my class files.

```
Aug 13, 2014 8:31:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsFile
SEVERE: Unable to process file [/home/rex/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/mod/test/TestData.class] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Utility.swallowMethodParameters(Utility.java:797)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Attribute.readAttribute(Attribute.java:171)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FieldOrMethod.<init>(FieldOrMethod.java:57)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Method.<init>(Method.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readMethods(ClassParser.java:267)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2058)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2033)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2026)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2026)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1291)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
```

I am using Tomcat 7.0.54 and JDK 8u5 x64
Any assistance will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed to be fixed in Tomcat 7.0.56

See changelog for Tomcat 7.0.56 http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html

Also tested this locally and it fixed my problems

Comment: I think it's fixed in 7.0.58: `57173: Revert the fix for 56953 that broke annotation scanning in some cases. (markt)`

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, you have to **disable** annotation processing, see this question [org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/tomcat7-and-java8-wont-start/23608847) for more information.

Comment: That flag works pretty well for automatically populating parameters on servlet request methods, Similar to Springs @PathVariable. This wasn't possible with the previous implementation, it's a welcome change in JAVA 8

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem and I resolved it without upgrading tomcat version as the following:

1. Changing the jaassist version ( i used the version 3.20.0-GA and i changed it to 3.18.1-GA)
2. adding some args to maven compiler plugin

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${plugin.compiler.version}</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>${project.build.javaVersion}</source>
           <target>${project.build.javaVersion}</target>
           <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
           <fork>true</fork>
           <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>             
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. adding the tag metadata-complete="true" to the web.xml