# Spark on Tomcat has exception IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, apache-spark

I've developed maven application that uses mongo-hadoop connector to pull data from mongodb and process it using Apache spark. The whole process runs smoothly if I run it on embedded Jetty server. However, if I deploy it to Tomcat server 7, it's always interrupted at the line of code which collects data from JavaPairRDD with exception that doesn't give me any clue what the problem might be:

```
15/07/09 20:42:05 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:58302 (size: 6.3 KB, free: 946.6 MB)
 15/07/09 20:42:05 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from newAPIHadoopRDD at SparkCategoryRecommender.java:106
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.spark.mapreduce.SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil$class.firstAvailableClass(SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.mapreduce.SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil$class.newJobContext(SparkHadoopMapReduceUtil.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.newJobContext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1779)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:47)
    at com.warrantylife.iqmetrix.spark.SparkCategoryRecommender.buildDataModelOnProductid(SparkCategoryRecommender.java:149)
    at com.warrantylife.iqmetrix.spark.SparkCategoryRecommender.computeAndStoreRecommendationsForProductsInCategory(SparkCategoryRecommender.java:179)
    at com.warrantylife.recommendation.impl.CategoryRecommendationManagerImpl.computeRecommendationsForCategory(CategoryRecommendationManagerImpl.java:105)
    at com.warrantylife.testdata.TestDataGeneratorService$1.run(TestDataGeneratorService.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I guess there is some library conflict happening on the Tomcat, but I have no idea where to look for problem.

This is my whole dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ warranty-analytics ---
[INFO] org.warrantylife:warranty-analytics:war:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6:system
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop:mongo-hadoop-core:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-p-provider:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.16:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO] |        \- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.mahout:mahout-core:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.mahout:mahout-math:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.mahout.commons:commons-cli:jar:2.0-mahout:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.solr:solr-commons-csv:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.mahout:mahout-integration:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.mahout:mahout-hdfs:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.mahout:mahout-mr:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-annotations:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.1.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jruby.jcodings:jcodings:jar:1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jruby.joni:joni:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-benchmark:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:53.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.17:compile
[INFO] |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting:randomizedtesting-runner:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.32:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.novemberain:quartz-mongodb:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.twitter:chill_2.10:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO]    |     +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:compile
[INFO]    |     \- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.10:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.10:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.10:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO]    +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.4.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-remote_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-actor_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.spark-project.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0-spark:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths:jar:1.2.2a:compile
[INFO]    +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-slf4j_2.10:jar:2.3.4-spark:compile
[INFO]    +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.scala-lang:scalap:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    |        \- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.mesos:mesos:jar:shaded-protobuf:0.21.1:compile
[INFO]    +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO]    +- org.tachyonproject:tachyon-client:jar:0.6.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.tachyonproject:tachyon:jar:0.6.4:compile
[INFO]    +- net.razorvine:pyrolite:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO]    +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.8.2.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile
```

**Edit:**
I solved this issue. It seems that the problem is in the combination of Java 8 and Tomcat 7. The problem disappeared after I migrated to the Tomcat 8.

Some related discussion that helped me to understand the problem:
[org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/tomcat7-and-java8-wont-start/23608847)

Comment: Why are you trying to run it on Tomcat if Jetty works just fine?

Comment: Because I've used Jetty for local development. Now I should deploy it on the customers server for his testing and he wants it on Tomcat.