# Does HippoCMS 7.8 support deploying with unexploded WAR files?

Tags: tomcat7, war, hippocms

Does HippoCMS 7.8 support deploying on Tomcat 7 using unexploded WAR files?

I have tried the following setup in my server.xml:

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="/apps/cms/webapps"
    unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false"
    deployXML="false">

    <Context
        path="/cms"
        docBase="public-cms-${hippo.version}"
        reloadable="false"
        crossContext="false">
        <Resource
            name="jdbc/repositoryDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" minIdle="2" initialSize="2" maxWait="10000"
            testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="select 1"
            poolPreparedStatements="true"
            username="**********" password="**********"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hippo" 
            />
    </Context>
</Host>
```

When I start up Tomcat, I get errors similar to the following in the `catalina.out` log:

```
Jul 16, 2015 5:46:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [ucar/nc2/iosp/hdf4/TagEnum.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/cms/WEB-INF/lib/netcdf-4.2-min.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(FastDataInputStream.java:120)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readAttributes(ClassParser.java:110)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Tomcat eventually reports a successful startup, but when I attempt to access the CMS webapp, I get a 500 error, with the message "Request processing executed 100 steps, which means it is probably in an infinite loop."

Everything works fine if I change the `unpackWARs` attribute back to `"true"` in the server.xml.

Comment: This may be a tomcat bug. What version of tomcat and java are you using?

Comment: It should be using tomcat6, but the bug I am thinking of wasn tomcat 7 and 8

Comment: btw, the minor version of tomcat is the important bit. I just saw you did mention tomcat 7.

Comment: @JasperFloor I am using Tomcat 7.0.57, Java 7u71

Comment: I'm thinking of this bug:https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57173

Which means it could be fixed if you grab a newer tomcat.

Comment: @JasperFloor, I tried both 7.0.59 and 7.0.63, and on both of them I didn't get the processAnnotationsJar errors during startup, and Tomcat reported starting up okay, but the site was responding with "HTTP Status 500 - Request processing executed 100 steps, which means it is probably in an infinite loop."

Comment: But if I set `unpackWARs="true"` it is works.

Comment: Then I guess it isn't that bug you are hitting. Not sure what is going on then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error message is due to annotation scanning in Tomcat 7. See also this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/tomcat7-and-java8-wont-start). AFAIK there are no known limitations for running Hippo CMS unexploded, but this is not most commonly used setup. You might want to disable annotation scanning and see if that solves the problem. If not it would be interesting to see another stacktrace.