# org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, classformatexception

I can't seem to get my server to start running. 
Don't know if this is relevant but using a lenovo yoga 2. 
tried a few of the suggested solutions but none of them seem to work.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1806)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1765)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1751)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1255)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

Comment: Have you tried this out already ? This applies if you are Java 8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/tomcat7-and-java8-wont-start

Comment: Refer [related question][1] this explains the problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/tomcat7-and-java8-wont-start

Answer (score 0):

First check if the tomcat port is being used by another app, the default port on tomcat is 8080

```js
netstat -an | find ":8080"
```

Also check your web.xml for dependencies.
This error also may be caused because you need to upgrade them, i have a similar issue and this was resolved updating icu4j to the latest version, this thread also may be helpful
http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Problem-when-mvn-site-site-Generating-quot-Dependencies-quot-report-td113470.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest that you download the latest version [ 7.0.63 ] as the older version were reported with bugs: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53735

Answer (score 0):

Please change metadata-complete="true" to metadata-complete="false" in web.xml