# Does Tomcat 6 support Java 8

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8

We are currently using Tomcat 6.0.20 and Java 7, but there is plan to get upgraded to Java 8. So wanted to know if Tomcat 6 would support Java 8.

Comment: Probably. You'll have to try it to be sure. A better question *is* **is Tomcat 6 supported**. Good luck.

Comment: Did you get chance to read documentation of tomcat6?

Comment: The current **supported** version of Tomcat 6 is [6.0.44](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) (you should probably upgrade) and Tomcat 6 is eol on [30 March 2017](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-60-eol.html)

Comment: Did you try a simple google search? It would've revealed that Tomcat 6 is listed as supporting Java 5 and later: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Tomcat itself will run, but some of its libraries may cause trouble. Compare to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23541532/2711488) which is about Tomcat 7 but highlights the problems you are likely to have to deal with Tomcat 6 as well…

Answer (score 5):

Yes it should as mentioned in release notes [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/RELEASE-NOTES.txt):

> Tomcat 6.0 is designed to run on Java SE 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

`Tomcat 6.x` is designed to run on `JDK 5.0` and later version. So it will support. But `Tomcat 6.x` cannot run on `JDK 1.4` and older releases.

[Apache Tomcat Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have Tomcat 6.0.35 running on Java 8.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this Answer is saying something that the other Answers are not?