# Deploying .war on Tomcat fails

Tags: linux, web, tomcat7

I'm trying to deploy web application by Tomcat Web Application Manager.

Deploying tomcat's sample.war succeeds,but deploying mytest.war exported from myeclise fails,why?

Uploading mytest.war succeed:

[image: files in the webapps directory]

Deploying fail:

[image: applications list]

Catalina log:

```
Mar 11, 2016 6:00:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive mytest.war
Mar 11, 2016 6:00:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive mytest.war
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in                                                                                         constant pool: 15
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.                                                                                        java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPoo                                                                                        l.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(Cl                                                                                        assParser.java:209)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.j                                                                                        ava:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(Co                                                                                        ntextConfig.java:1930)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(Conte                                                                                        xtConfig.java:1826)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(Conte                                                                                        xtConfig.java:1785)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextC                                                                                        onfig.java:1771)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav                                                                                        a:1254)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi                                                                                        g.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi                                                                                        g.java:316)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl                                                                                        eSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa                                                                                        se.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex                                                                                        t.java:5103)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase                                                                                        .java:812)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:78                                                                                        7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:529                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1377)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                        java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                                        sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.j                                                                                        ava:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultM                                                                                        BeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:                                                                                        1422)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServ                                                                                        let.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServ                                                                                        let.java:209)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl                                                                                        icationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF                                                                                        ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPrevent                                                                                        ionFilter.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl                                                                                        icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF                                                                                        ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV                                                                                        alve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV                                                                                        alve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica                                                                                        torBase.java:576)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j                                                                                        ava:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j                                                                                        ava:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:                                                                                        563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal                                                                                        ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav                                                                                        a:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java                                                                                        :317)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce                                                                                        ss(Http11Protocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce                                                                                        ss(Http11Protocol.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin                                                                                        t.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                                                                        java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                                                                        .java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I hava found my anwser from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in)

Answer (score 0):

please take a look to $CATALINA_HOME/logs/, especially $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out

BR
Chris

Comment: This looks much more like a comment than an answer. Though you don't have reputation enough to comment, it might be a good idea to try and avoid commenting in answers.