# JAX-RS issue in Maven pom

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs, maven-dependency-plugin

I am learning JAX-RS. I tried to configure the pom file with respective dependencies but I still faced these issues.

WEB.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <!-- <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file> 
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file> 
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file> <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> 
        </welcome-file-list> -->
    <display-name>User Management</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.practise.restful</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My pom file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>UserManagement</groupId>
<artifactId>UserManagement</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse/yasson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My REST service is deployed on Tomcat 8.5 server. The client application is  a dynamic web project

Exception :

```
   Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 6 2016 20:15:31 UTC
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.6.0
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\pruth\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\pruth\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\pruth\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\endorsed
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Users\pruth\Anaconda3;C:\Users\pruth\Anaconda3\Scripts;D:\pruthvi\softwares\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;D:\pruthvi\softwares\apache-maven-3.5.0;C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\lib;C:\Users\pruth\Anaconda3;C:\Users\pruth\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\pruth\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\pruth\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\pruth\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\pruth\eclipse\jee-neon3\eclipse;;.
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7543"]
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-7433"]
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 968 ms
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:11 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\pruth\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\UserManagement.xml
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
**WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:UserManagement' did not find a matching property.
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
**SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [file:/C:/Users/pruth/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/UserManagement/WEB-INF/lib/yasson-1.0.jar] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19****
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:54)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:174)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2053)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2000)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1923)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1163)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 23, 2017 3:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
**SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [file:/C:/Users/pruth/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/UserManagement/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json.bind-api-1.0.jar] for annotations**
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:54)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:174)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2053)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2000)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1923)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1163)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 23, 2017 3:01:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
**SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [file:/C:/Users/pruth/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/UserManagement/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.1.jar] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19**
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:54)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:174)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2053)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2000)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1923)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1163)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 23, 2017 3:01:12 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet JAX-RS Servlet as unavailable
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
**SEVERE: Servlet [JAX-RS Servlet] in web application [/UserManagement] threw load() exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: No servlet class has been specified for servlet JAX-RS Servlet
    at** org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5223)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 23, 2017 3:01:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\pruth\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\UserManagement.xml has finished in 1,149 ms
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-7543]
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-7433]
Jul 23, 2017 3:01:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1858 ms
```

Comment: Probably the most important exception is this `javax.servlet.ServletException: No servlet class has been specified for servlet JAX-RS Servlet`.

Comment: Please show us your web.xml

Comment: @vikarjramun updated with web.xml

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: FYI you misspelled `practice` :)

Comment: @halfer thanks for the edit

Comment: It seems that you have two Servlet mappings. Try removing the JAX-RS Servlet and respective Servlet mapping. **This is mere speculation... make sure you save the original in case it completely destroys your project**

Comment: @vikarjramun   edited it but no change...I changed my WEB.xml accordingly here

Comment: @PruthviU.V.S.S I am not sure what to do. Thank you so much for trying the changes I asked you for, I am sorry I couldn't be of more assistance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in)