# I'm trying to write a Jersey 2 Web Service in Tomcat 8. But am stumped by error

Tags: java, web-services, jersey-2.0, noclassdeffounderror

```
Sep 27, 2017 5:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/bind/JsonbException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:800)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceBagConfigurator.init(ResourceBagConfigurator.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.json.bind.JsonbException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 40 more

Sep 27, 2017 5:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey REST Service] in web application [/ExtraTechAutoSysSDKWS] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.json.bind.JsonbException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:800)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceBagConfigurator.init(ResourceBagConfigurator.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The errors occur at the time I try and run the app on the Tomcat web server within my IDE, so I'm assuming it's a deployment issue.

Does anyone have an idea why this may be happening?

I downloaded **jaxrs-ri-2.26.zip** from [here](https://jersey.github.io/download.html)

I'm trying to use it with Tomcat 8.

I've had to tweak **catalina.properties**
*tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip*
for these jars:

```
javax.json-api-1.1.jar
javax.json-1.1.jar
```

per this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in) regarding BPEL issues.
Of the form:

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar... for annotations 
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
```

I have been using Spring Tool Suite, where I created a Dynamic Web Project.

I used this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_agJFIB9bw) series as a guideline.

In the WebContext\WEB-INF\lib folder, I have the following jars.

```
hk2-api-2.5.0-b42.jar
hk2-locator-2.5.0-b42.jar
hk2-utils-2.5.0-b42.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar
javax.json-1.1.jar
javax.json-api-1.1.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-hk2.jar
jersey-media-jaxb.jar
jersey-media-json-binding.jar
jersey-media-sse.jar
jersey-server.jar
servlet-api-3.1.jar
```

java -version yields:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: If someone gave this a -1 can you let me know why? What else is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a missing jar

```
javax.json.bind-api-1.0.jar
```

and that also had to be added to the catalina.properties to be skipped...

It was also missing:

```
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

That got me to the point app would deploy...

Answer (score 0):

The error says you don't have javax.json.bind included. I googled for it and found it here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api