# Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19 error message

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

This error message shows that the Tomcat is 8.0.30, and I am using JDK 8. I am creating a Spring-boot project. Some suggested that JDK 8 should be used but I indeed am using JDK 8. What's the problem here?

```
信息: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
十月 18, 2018 12:26:19 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
信息: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/export/Domains/nluqe.jd.com/server1/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
十月 18, 2018 12:26:19 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
警告: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
十月 18, 2018 12:26:32 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
严重: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/home/export/App/nluqe.jd.com/WEB-INF/lib/lombok-1.16.22.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:55)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:176)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2011)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1961)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1936)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1897)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1149)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1777)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
十月 18, 2018 12:26:34 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
严重: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/home/export/App/nluqe.jd.com/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:55)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:176)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2011)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1961)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1936)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1897)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1149)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1777)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Updated (I want to configure not scanning annotation per suggestions):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <bean id="executorService" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" factory-method="newFixedThreadPool">
        <constructor-arg value="20"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- jsf -->
    <import resource="jsf-context.xml"/>


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>


    <bean class="com.jd.ump.annotation.JAnnotation">

        <property name="systemKey" value="com.nlu-qe-service.systemKey"></property>

        <property name="jvmKey" value="com.nlu-qe-service.jvmKey"></property>
    </bean>


    </beans>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in

Comment: @SudhirOjha, how to add "metadata-complete="true" to web.xml? My application doesn't have a web.xml file. It only has a spring-base.xml under the "spring" directory. Please see my updated spring-base.xml. How to add this 'metadata' to it? I am very new to Spring.

Comment: If this is caused by `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0`, have a look at `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1`.

Comment: See Answer may help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in/63339038#63339038

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tomcat 8.0 has reached End of Life and should not be used!

The replacement is Tomcat 8.5 (implementing the same specifications as Tomcat 8.0) or Tomcat 9.0 (newer versions of specifications). See "Migration Guide" at tomcat.apache.org.

> org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)

The BCEL library here is used to parse class files when Tomcat scans for annotations. The version that you are using does not support some features in class file format of Java 8, and thus fails when trying to parse the file.

Your options:

1. Ignore.
2. Upgrade Tomcat.
3. Exclude those jars from annotation scanning. (See the official Tomcat FAQ → Performance → How do I make Tomcat start up faster?).

Comment: upgrading to tomcat 9 as well didn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In order to upgrade the tomcat version for the tomcat7-maven-plugin.

```
<properties>
    <tomcat7-version>7.0.93</tomcat7-version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat7-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to downgrade the version of glassfish packages in your dependencies.
Had the problem with 2.30.1 version (and Tomcat 8.5 Server), no more issue after changing to 2.22.2.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I also got same issue. I just changed aspectjrt and aspectjweaver jar version to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Try this one might work for you also.

Comment: it doesn't work in my case, and I even tested the latest 1.9 version. None worked. Given my xml configuration file above, how can I add the  "metadata-complete="true"? I have no web.xml file.

Comment: Hi try to check lombok jar once

Comment: What do you mean by checking "lombok jar"?

Comment: Check exception stack trace

Comment: Did you get any clue?