# Cannot run tomcat7:run in maven project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

working on a maven project I get the following error when I try to 'mvn tomcat7:run' so to start the app in an embed tomcat.

I have searched SO answers in similar questions but nothing solves the issue.

> Tomcat plugin: tomcat7-maven-plugin v2.2

Could this be due to maven libraries version mismatch?

```
    SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/Users/George/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.0/jackson-annotations-2.11.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jun 02, 2020 8:07:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/Users/George/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.0.rc1/jackson-core-2.11.0.rc1.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jun 02, 2020 8:07:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/Users/George/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jun 02, 2020 8:07:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/Users/George/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.0/jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the  version but based on your command if you are using tomcat7 you may need to upgrade, see:

[Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19 error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867430/invalid-byte-tag-in-constant-pool-19-error-message)

Comment: added this plugin org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-tomcat:jar:1.7.6