# java 8 , tamcat 8: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, tomcat8

I have a problem when i start the server.

I Use java 8 and tomcat 8

Don't know how to fix that.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:55)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:176)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2042)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1988)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1958)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1912)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1157)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5202)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What to problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: Not sure look similar to me :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in

Comment: Tag 19 doesn't exist in V8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4 are you sure you don't have classes that were compiled with a more recent version?

Comment: I was re-downloaded "eclipse" before I written this maven project.
now I have eclipse version 4.9.0.
Is there a connection between things?

Comment: And I'm sure it Tomcat V8.0

Comment: Did you solved this @ChayMizrahi?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add below code on Server ->Tomcat ->catalina.properties and clean module work directory.

   ```
    tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip
    junit.jar,junit-*.jar,ant-launcher.jar,\
    jfxrt.jar,nashorn.jar***strong text***
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Tomcat 8.0.46.