# Spring boot application started fail with tomcat 7 jdk1.8

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy my Spring boot application on a Tomcat 7 server and start it. 
When I start I have : **org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina] Server startup in 11954 ms**

But I get the issues below and my deployment failed:

```
  Unable to process Jar entry [META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:tomcat/7_0_61-ep-01/webapps/app-oss/WEB-INF/lib/byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar!/] for annotations
    org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:55)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:177)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2089)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1965)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1931)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1916)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1882)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:tools/tomcat/7_0_61-ep-01/webapps/app-oss/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:55)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:177)     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1882)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Depencies springboot :

```
ging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

How can I fix it ?
I edited my post for adding one part of dependencies springboot .. The package is a WAR and I exclude tomcat

Comment: is this a maven project?? did you add any dependency in pom.xml

Comment: Yes it is a maven .. I try to migrate spring application to spring boot application ... When I remove all dependencies of spring-bvoot it is worked well .. but when I add springboot not work .. I will update çy post for adding my pom

Comment: Seems like jdk and tomcat versions aren't compatible try deploying in higher version of tomcat may be 8 or above see below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in

Comment: Ok, but why does it work when I use spring ? and not work with spring boot ?with the same versions tomcat 7 and jdk 1.8

Comment: you must have compiled the code in java 7. as you saying you are migrating OLD codes to spring boot. >just guessing

Comment: Yes it is right ... So it is not possible ?

Comment: check the link as I suggested in my answer. give a try with the tomcat 9.x and make your life easier. even 9 .x is free

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in)

Answer (score 1):

Your application is packaged as a jar file. In order to deploy it to tomcat you need to pack it as a war file and add tomcat dependency. You can do this in your pom.xml as follows:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

By default spring boot produces a jar file after packaging and has an embedded tomcat server. To run it only JRE is required. If you need to deploy it to tomcat follow the above steps.

Comment: Yes in the pom.xml the package is a war (I edited my post for adding one part of the pom) .. But tomcat is in <exclusions> .. I dont want to use embedded tomcat ..

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat version is not compatible with the one you are using in jdk. 
see this article shows it clearly http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html
some time you can get hints from quora to https://www.quora.com/Is-Tomcat-7-compatible-with-JDK-8

Comment: yes I checked links .. but I dont understand why I got issues with springboot and not with spring ... means I can use tomcat7 / jdk1.8 with my spring project and springboot ?

Comment: all I can say is, you are getting error related to byte code. that means tomcat container is not able to read it though your jar/war created successfully. so there wasn't issue in code.

Comment: Ok I got it.. Thanks for your help