# Starting tomcat failed with Invalid byte code error

Tags: java, tomcat

When trying to start the tomcat, it is failed with the below error. I read many articles everything is pointing out the problem is in Tomcat 7 but I am facing the problem in Tomcat 8. But the same was running in my local machine with JDK8.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:55)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:177)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2012)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1962)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1937)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1149)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Jdk Version: `1.8.0_181`
Tomcat Version:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
Server built:   Jan 23 2015 11:56:07 UTC
Server number:  8.0.18.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.14.181-140.257.amzn2.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_181-b13
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

There are similar questions in StackOverflow suggesting it should be fixed by upgrading in Tomcat8. But we are already using tomcat 8 here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in)

Comment: @Holy_diver no, we are already using tomcat8.