# maven web project with error org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: It is not a Java .class file

Tags: java, maven, web, tomcat

I am using maven to build a web project,  there are some class files in my project under WebContent/WEB-INF/Classes. The names are org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet, org.apache.axis2.webapp.AdminAgent and org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.They are all class files and can be decompiled. When I build the war package with the mvn package command, I get an error when I run it in tomcat:

```
31-Aug-2021 14:10:26.235 严重 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource Unable to process web resource [/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/axis2/transport/http/AxisAdminServlet.class] for annotations
 org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: It is not a Java .class file
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2082)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1981)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1146)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

And I took out the above class files from the webapp of tomcat, and found that it could not be decompiled.
My maven configuration is as follows

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>WebContent/axis2-web</directory>
                            <targetPath>axis2-web</targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>WebContent/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Did maven change the class files in building? How do I configure pom.xml to ensure that maven does not make changes to these class files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/org-apache-tomcat-util-bcel-classfile-classformatexception-invalid-byte-tag-in Might Help!

Comment: Hello, did you resolve this issue? Please, could you give me an advice?